# Allowing Cookies in the Apollo GraphQL playground (version 3)

Tags: cookies, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-playground

According to the apollo [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/studio/explorer/#cookies):

> If your server uses cookies to authenticate, you can configure your endpoint to share those cookies with https://studio.apollographql.com.
> To set this up, your cookie's value must contain `SameSite=None; Secure`. Additionally, these CORS headers must be present in your server's response to Studio:
>
> ```
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://studio.apollographql.com
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
> ```

I have done everything mentioned there. I am using express, so I used the cors middleware to set the headers:

```
 app.use(
    cors({
      credentials: true,
      origin: "https://studio.apollographql.com",
    })
  );
```

But still whenever I turn on the toggele for "Allow Cookies" in the playground, the status goes red (*i.e., "Unable to reach server"*). My editor and nodemon show no errors. Turning off the Allow Cookies toggle solves the problem but disables the cookie functionality.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the cors middleware, you may need to set the cors in the apollo.applyMiddleware to false and let your cors middleware works.

```
  app.use(
    cors({
      credentials: true,
      origin: "https://studio.apollographql.com",
    })
  );

...

  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    cors: false, 
  });
```

Or, you could also use the cors option provided by the apollo-server instead.

```
  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    cors: {
      origin: 'https://studio.apollographql.com',
      credentials: true,
    },
  });
```